# How to handle polymorphism without casting object?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance

```
 class A{
    int a;
    
    public int getA(){
        return a;
    } 
    
    public void setA(int a){
        this.a=a;
    }
}
```

// Class B extending A class and add one additional variable

```
 class B extends A{
    int b;
    public int getB(){
        return b;
    } 
    
    public void setB(int b){
        this.b=b;
    }
}
```

// this is the main class

```
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        A aa;
          if(runtime conditon)   {         
                aa= new B();
                  aa.setA(3);
                  ((B)aa).setB(4); 
            }
          else{
          aa= new A();
                  aa.setA(3);
          }
}
}
```

How to design to solve the above problem without using casting?
sorry for asking the low-level question (I am new to java).

Comment: In your first condition, create an instance of `B` and assign it to `B`, make you changes and then assign that instance to `aa`

Comment: For polymorphism to work, you should read about the Liskov Substitution Principle. This means that all subclasses of A should be usable as A objects. In your case, I would move the set/get B methods into A.

Comment: In real life, the best example I can think of is the view hierarchy of a gui library, such as Swing.

Answer (score 1):

Since class B extends class A you can use a variable of type A to point to a variable of type B.
But if you want to use only one variable of type A (in your case `aa`) you cannot use a method of class B without casting the object.

Because you have to remember that when you use a variable (in your case type A) that points to a derived type use (in your case type B), you can only use the methods that are defined in class A, the rest are obscured. By casting the object to its true type you can use all of its methods.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce another variable:

```
B bb= new B();
bb.setA(3);
bb.setB(4); 
aa = bb;
```

Comment: if i want to pass in another class

C.test(aa)

class C{
 
 public static void test(A a){
      and i want print b value here  i think it's not work
 }
}

Comment: @KuldeepSingh that's not what you asked in the question.

Comment: If you want to print a value from B, you need to make sure (to you and to the compiler) that the instance really is of type B or one of its subtypes. So, don't declare a variable to be of type A if you really need type B.